# How do i know when to use Debug mode or Release mode in flutter?

Tags: flutter, release-mode, debug-mode

I am new in flutter. Help me guys. I am currently working making simple apps in flutter. And I just found about new release mode and debug mode in flutter. I want to know which mode does what in flutter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps in debug mode has a bigger size, because load libraries to allow the hot reload and hot restart
In release mode hot reload and hard reload isn't available for the same reason, and recommend use release mode for presentations and depending for some tests